# Getting an array of all rows in a MySQL table that meet a criteria

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working on a discord.js bot and so I am working in Node.Js. What I need to do is search through my MySQL table and get all rows that meet a criteria (which I can do) and then return the value in first column of all those rows meeting said criteria. I have tried multiple different methods, but my main issue is I can't return that value. I can `console.log` it from within my query, but I really need to return it.

```
function fetchOrders(status){
    textr = con.query(`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OStatus = '${status}';`, function(err,rows) {
                if(err){
                    throw err
                }
                var text = "";
                if(rows.length<1){
                    text = "None"
                }else{
                    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                        text = text + "`" + rows[i].OID.toString() + "`, "
                    }
                }
                if(text===""){
                    text = "None"
                }
                return text;
            })
    return textr    
}
```

The value `text` is what I need (up to `return text;` it works perfectly), but when I return it `textr` is not `text`. If someone could tell me how to get `text` out of my query, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this function to be promise style like this

```
function fetchOrders(status) {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OStatus = '${status}';`, function(
      err,
      rows
    ) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      var text = "";
      if (rows.length < 1) {
        text = "None";
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          text = text + "`" + rows[i].OID.toString() + "`, ";
        }
      }
      if (text === "") {
        text = "None";
      }
      resolve(text);
    });
  });
}
```

and call it like this

```
fetchOrders
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
```

OR

```
const response = await fetchOrders();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Although I do not really understand promises this seems to make sense to me. I will have a go at applying this.

Comment: this link might help you - https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, I finally managed to get my code working based on your solution. You're a lifesaver. Thank you very much! (That guide on promises etc also looks very helpful so thank you for that too)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not familiar with asynchronous calls in node. Calls that accept a callback are usually executed asynchronously, which means that the result of the call will not be available immediately (not even after the function call ended), but as soon as the result is available, the callback will be called.

You can modify your code to accept another callback, so that your function has a chance to do something with the query results, and then notify the caller:

```
function fetchOrders(status, callback){
    con.query(`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OStatus = '${status}';`, function(err,rows) {
        if(err){
            callback(err);
        }
        var text = "";
        if(rows.length<1){
            text = "None"
        }else{
            for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                text = text + "`" + rows[i].OID.toString() + "`, "
            }
        }
        if(text===""){
            text = "None"
        }

        callback(null, text);
    })
}
```

Note that the functions don't return anymore, but pass the value (or error) to the callback. This requires changing also the code that calls this function, so that instead of:

```
var result = fetchOrders(status);
```

you need to write:

```
fetchOrders(status, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    // do something with result
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that - can I put a `return result` inside the function you wrote to get my value out or should I still be using something else?

Comment: @JackBarrett, unfortunately that is not possible, cause the return value of the callback functions is never used. If you want to write your code in a more synchronous-looking way, I suggest you to follow Ashish's approach.